# What can this closure, ()->() do in swift?

Tags: swift, closures

I have known something about the closures in swift, and I know **()->()** means it takes no parameters and returns nothing, but, what can it do?
The codes is here:

```
var tick:(()->())?
var tickLengthMillis = NSTimeInterval(600)
var lastTick:NSDate?

var timePassed= lastTick!.timeIntervalSinceNow*-1000.0
if timePassed > tickLengthMillis {
    lastTick = NSDate()
    tick?()
}
```

What does that **tick?()** do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could produce some log output. Or advance a progress bar. Or any other kind of side effect.

Comment: So you mean at here, the tick() actually did nothing? I'm still confused

Comment: In the code you show `tick` is null (it is, after all, optional). So nothing gets called. But you could set it to a closure that does something,

Comment: Looks like this closure is like some placeholders, and I can do something or do nothing as I wish, right?

Answer (score 1):

In your code the closure `tick`is a `nil`, you can give it a value by
`tick = {//any execution here}`
you can treat it as a function without any parameter and returns nothing

`tick?()`means to 'execute the closure if it is not a `nil`'

Answer (score -1):

It is used for functions (or methods) that take a closure. Since a closure can be anything, you could pass it ()->().

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> ()) {
    // function body goes here
}

// here's how you call this function without using a trailing closure:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure({
    // closure's body goes here
})

// here's how you call this function with a trailing closure instead:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure() {
    // trailing closure's body goes here
}
```

That "tick" variable is of type "optional closure" so it can be nil or a closure of some type. If you change the closure that is in the variable, it would be called in the "if" statement bellow.